# Spring Boot REST (OAUTH2 JWT) @AuthenticationPrincipal returns null for custom UserDetails

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

**Context:** I have a Spring Boot REST API secured with oauth2 JWT, this part works properly.

**Problem:** In my RestController I want to access the currently authenticated user's ID with `@AuthenticationPrincipal User userDetails` but it returns `null`.

**Security Filter Chain:**

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        return http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                {
                    auth.requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/auth/**")).permitAll();
                    auth.requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/admin/**")).hasAnyRole("ADMIN");
                    auth.requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/user/**")).hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN");
                    auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                        .jwt(jwtConfigurer -> jwtConfigurer.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter()))
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(invalidTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                )
                .exceptionHandling(exception ->
                        exception.authenticationEntryPoint(authRequiredAuthenticationEntryPoint))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .build();
    }
```

**User Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User extends AbstractTimestampEntity implements UserDetails
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_role_junction",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")}
    )
    private Set<Role> authorities;

    // Constructor for manual user creation
    public User(String username, String email, String password, Set<Role> authorities)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**User Details Service implementation**

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService
{
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserDetailsServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository)
    {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException
    {
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User does not exists!"));
    }
}
```

**User Controller**

```
package com.jez.blogapi.controller;

import com.jez.blogapi.model.User;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController
{
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getUserById(@AuthenticationPrincipal User userDetails)
    {
        System.out.println(userDetails);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("test response message", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: UserDetails has nothing to do with JWT, `oauth2ResourceServer`. It is null because if you pass a JWT to a spring service, it will validate the token, but it will not load any user details since a token is not a session and it is stateless. If you want the id, you need to put it in the jwt token as a claim.

Comment: So basically, I have to put every data I need about the user into the JWT, and then extract it in the controller?

Comment: or you give up using JWT tokens and resource server since it is not what you want and instead implement FormLogin

Comment: I don't agree with last comment: configuring a REST API as a stateless resource server is a good idea, you should stick with it: it makes it very scalable and fault tolerant. Moreover, what is the point of configuring OAuth2 client and request & store tokens if you never use it to query an OAuth2 resource server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resource server build the security-context out of the access token, either by decoding it (if it's a JWT), or introspecting it (whatever the format).

In case of JWT, there is a [chapter in the doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-architecture) explaining how it works, and you should read it.

If you stick with the default `Authentication` implementation with JWT decoders (`JwtAuthenticationToken`), then `@AuthenticationPrincipal` should return a `org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt` from which you can read claims (provided that the request was authorised with a valid `Bearer` JWT).

So, yes, as you suggest in the comments to your question, enriching access tokens (when creating it on the authorization server) with all of the user data you need on your resource server(s), seems a better idea
than looping to the database for each and every REST API call.

If there are claims you need to access frequently, you could configure the `jwtAuthenticationConverter` to return your own extension of `AbstractAuthenticationToken` (instead of `JwtAuthenticationToken`). It is rather simple and allows to return typed values from named accessors (and de-couple your application code from your authorization server claims structure).

##### P.S.

OAuth2 resource servers are queried by OAuth2 clients but mobile and Javascript based applications (Angular, Vue, React, etc) make unsafe OAuth2 clients.

The [current recommendation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390) from Spring Security team is to use "confidential" clients on the server.

For mobile and Javascript based applications, I use `spring-cloud-gateway` (with `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` and `TokenRelay=` filter) in front of my stateless resource servers. In this architecture, requests are authorized with:

- sessions between the front-end and the (stateful) gateway
- Bearer JWT between the gateway and the (stateless) REST APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation this is kind of a learning project for me. For now, I made it like this:
I access the Jwt form AuthenticationPrincipal and added the user's ID as the 'sub' to the Jwt so I can read it in the controller.

Comment: You could find my tutorials useful: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials there is, among other things, a complete BFF sample (in case you want a Javascript based front-end)

Comment: Don't skip the README. There is some useful I for on the répo main README too.